# Allow non-ssl content from external websites in an HTTPS website under IIS

Tags: iis, ssl, cross-domain

I recently put my website under SSL. I've been able to adapt the website so that most of the content is under SSL, but some data, like Twitter avatars, are on an http website, so I'm receiving warnings, at least in Chrome.

Is there a policy in IIS to enable fetching non-ssl data from pages outside website's domain?

Is it depending on browser, on the source code, or on server settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insert direct HTTP links, the browser will complain (and this is correct). One of the options is to cache the data on your server and send it as "own" links for the server.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I wasn't sure it was a good practice. But I must be sure this isn't a copyright violation. Is there a clean way to 'cache' things with IIS or I need to rely on some HttpWebRequests (on .Net)?

Comment: I don't think you can have such "cache" with IIS out of the box (maybe some plugins or addons exist). As for copyright violation - you need to check with your lawyer, but for me your service acts like a caching proxy, as much as ISPs proxies do, so I doubt that there can be any space for copyright violation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it will, but the browser will complain about unsecured links usually.

Comment: Ok, so the equation 'SSL + unsecure content = warning' comes from browsers.

Comment: Yes. At least as far as I researched for a similar question.